# Does Web Audio API works in UWP apps?

Tags: uwp, audiocontext

One of the methods I read to see if the browser supports the Web Audio API is using the following code:

```
if (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext) {
    audio_context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
} else {
    notSupported();
    return;
}
```

UWP has the Audio Context object, but I am facing some weird limitations with visualizations of the audio stream. I got one official demo web application, but for Microsoft Edge, and I thought it could work in UWP as well. Is that a correct assumption? Should I try a different framework?

Comment: What kind of weird limitations are you facing? And which official demo are you using? Are you planning to use [hosted web app](http://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/HWA.htm) or simply embed source codes into a UWP(JS) App?

Comment: "What kind of weird limitations are you facing?" ->

When I try to create an array data from the audio buffer, all values from the array are zero. And then I can't render the audio wave...

"And which official demo are you using?" ->

I am using this demo [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/Demos/tree/master/microphone)

I am using simply embed source codes into a UWP (JS)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works. Basing my solution in the [demo](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/Demos/tree/master/microphone) provided, I decided to remove the function applyEffects(). It was a mistake, since this function requested the wav default file and updated the buffer in convolver variable. Returning this function and just using the default values, I could access the information I wanted.

In summary: Yes, it works in UWP(JS) Apps!